# exiting julia runtime embedded in python

Tags: python, julia, ctypes

My question is I want to know if it is possible to exit a Julia runtime embedded into a Python application without terminating the application.

Below is a description of my use case:

I have an application that is mainly in python and I have move some computationally heavy routines to Julia for performance. I have wrapped the julia part Julia C API:

- Julia functions are wrapped as C function using the @ccallable interface.
- I make a Julia dll using PackageCompiler
- python interface with it using ctypes
- python initialize the Julia library using ctypes.CDLL and the julia C API.
- the julia runtime is initialized by calling jl_init_with_image() through the DLL.

All this works very well but now I want to be able to exit the Julia runtime without killing my python application. I want to do this because the python application is meant to be running for a long period of time and the Julia runtime has a very large memory footprint. Therefore, it would be great to be able to only have the Julia runtime being on only when my application need it.

**Edit**

here is a minimal working example for a linux machine:

**minimal_example.py**

```
import os
import ctypes
from ctypes import Structure, c_int8, c_char_p, c_int32
import time


julialibpath = f"/path/to/libjulia.so"


assert os.path.isfile(julialibpath)
julialib = ctypes.CDLL(julialibpath, ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)


julialib.jl_init.argtypes= []
julialib.jl_init()
print("initialize julia")



time.sleep(5)


print("exit julia")
julialib.jl_exit(0)
print("julia reinitialize")
julialib.jl_init()
```

In this example the python script will terminate after calling jl_exit and the print statement on the next line is not executed.

Is there a way to to this with the python interpreter remaining active?

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could this be worked around using the *Python* wrappers (*PyJulia*)?

Comment: Since the python program is to run for a long period of time, and so run time may not matter, it might be best to run the Julia program via subprocess.run() or subprocess.call() and write results to a file.  That should clean up all memory used by Julia well, though it will take much longer to start up each time.

Comment: What about calling `jl_atexit_hook(0);` instead ?

Comment: @CristiFati It seems to me that jl_atexit_hook() does some cleanup in preparation for exiting the runtime but does not exit it.

Comment: @CristiFati would you have a suggestion in using PyJulia for this? Because from my understanding it still rely on the Julia C API to manage the runtime.

Comment: I didn't use it, it was just a suggestion. What about calling the hook function then manually (forcibly) unloading the *.dll*?